# Azure Node.Js SendGrid has no method 'send'

Tags: node.js, azure, sendgrid

I'm using Azure Mobile Service with Node.Js, and I need to send email with SendGrid, but I receive an

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'send' at exports.post**

error message.

Here is my code:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
  var user = '<user>';
  var key = '<key>';
  var sendgrid = require('sendgrid');

  sendgrid.api_user = user;
  sendgrid.api_key = key;

  var email = new sendgrid.Email({
      to: 'my_email@mail.com',
      from: 'test@sendgrid.com',
      subject: 'This is the subject.',
      text: 'This is the body.'
  });

  sendgrid.send(email, function (err, json) {
      if (err) { return console.error(err); }
      console.log(json);
  });

  request.respond(200);}
```

Why fails Azure SendGrid? Not correct version installed with the Node.Js? How can I access the Node.Js with npm (Node Package Manager) to reinstall the SendGrid package? Or something goes wrong? (The SendGrid already has "send" method, you can check it via GitHub.)

Thanks a lot for any kind of help!
Sandor

Comment: You should also post the code which makes use of this module

Comment: I'm calling it from a simple HTTP POST now (to test it), via Fiddler. It returns with HTTP error 500, Internal Server error, and with the error message above.

Comment: Can we see that simple HTTP Post?

Comment: Here is my post:

POST http://xxxxxxxxx.azure-mobile.net/api/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: xxxxxxxxxxxx.azure-mobile.net
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 2

Body:
{}

Comment: You'll need to edit your original answer, I think

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.
The reference to the sendgrid is not an object. I have to make a SendGrid object, and it has a "send" method.

The correct code is:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {

var user = '<user>';
var key = '<key>';
var sendgridReference = require('sendgrid');

var sendgridObject = new sendgridReference.SendGrid();

sendgridObject.api_user = user;
sendgridObject.api_key = key;

var email = new sendgridReference.Email({
    to: 'my_email@mail.com',
    from: 'test@sendgrid.com',
    subject: 'This is the subject.',
    text: 'This is the body.'
});

sendgridObject.send(email, function (err, json) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err); }
    console.log(json);
});

request.respond(200);
```

};

Comment: Your original question is that you just declared the module `sendgrid`, but hadn't involved. The code example on [official site](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/nodejs.html), involved sendgrid construction function when first requiring it. It is the JavaScript self-involving feature, you can check at this [API reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp). And in your solution, you had involved sendgrid function.